# Preencher variavel do inspector via codigo unity

Tags: unity-5

Estou tentando o seguinte:

Quando o inimigo for instanciado quero que ele tenha como alvo
o meu jogador, tudo certo, mas quando o inimigo vem ao jogo ele não preenche a variável `Alvo` como eu indiquei abaixo, no inspetor fica como (none).

```
var Alvo  : Transform;

function Update () {
    if (!Alvo)
 {
   Alvo = GameObject.Find("/Tanque").transform;  
 }
```

Comment: Por que tu tá passando `/`? Isso é pra percorrer a hierarquia, teu objeto "Tanque" tá dentro de outro objeto?

Comment: sim ele esta dentro de outro objeto

Comment: Tenta fazer então "OutroObjeto\Tanque".

Comment: blz, vou fzr agora

Comment: opa, voltei, deu certo, ficou assim o codigo:

Comment: if (!Alvo) 
                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                           Alvo = GameObject.Find("tanque/Tanque").transform;  
                                                                                                                    }

Comment: porem tentei colocar esse codigo no start, e deu certo.

Comment: Quero agradecer pela atenção, muito obrigado!

Comment: Responda sua própria pergunta, só pra ficar como referência para as próximas pessoas que virem isso poderem tirar da solução :)